Personalize the visual map123
In PowerBI, with the map123 visual, I want to display the different dates present in the segment visual as below.
enter image description here
The map123 visual only displays a date.
Is it possible to display the selection of the segment visual in the map123 visual?
I searched for the solution on the internet without success, I have the impression that it is not possible.
